# R package, fOptions is no longer available

Tags: r, lattice, cran

I need to install R package fOpitons for a learning module required by society of actuaries. This package seems to be no longer available on CRAN. It was taken down in April 2022 for misrepresentation of authorship and ownership of copyright. None of the links to former versions of the package works. How can I install this package?

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fOptions/index.html

None of the links in this site works.
https://cran-archive.r-project.org/web/checks/2022/2022-04-29_check_results_fOptions.html

Answer (score 3):

(Note for eager "close as duplicate":  the Archive/ link for this package is (currently?) broken which is *very unusual* for CRAN so I spelled out alternative approaches below. That part is likely not a duplicate.  Cheers.  -D.)

CRAN packages are open source, and even when removed from the current CRAN index for reasons deemed necessary by the CRAN team will *always* remain available in the Archive/ section of the package.

So the link you provide has as its second line

> Formerly available versions can be obtained from the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/fOptions).

where the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/fOptions) link *should* provide you access to various versions.

However, it is not working, which looks like an error.  So I just alerted CRAN to that.

I happen to have maintained fOptions in Debian for a number of years. So you still get the Debian binary packages -- and sources. Most recent versions are at https://packages.debian.org/sid/r-cran-foptions point for example to the source archive:  http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/foptions/foptions_3042.86.orig.tar.gz

If you can install from source this should do.

Otherwise, there is also a CRAN mirror at GitHub so
https://github.com/cran/fOptions is another choice.

Comment: It would also be worth alerting the Society of Actuaries to the situation. Presumably they will need to modify their syllabus because of this problem.

Comment: It appears the SOA has been notified of this issue. The crucial functions needed for Scenario Modeling Modules are now provided in the Module Contents for use in the reports.

Comment: Cran deprecated it because of misuse see my answer below. It is still available on Rmetrics github page and works just fine.

Comment: I am a windows 11 user and use R 4.3.1 and it runs just fine.

Comment: There has been no changes to any functions in any Rmetrics library since 2015 largely and mostly only cosmetic changes, especially since founding member of Rmetrics Diethelm Wuertz passed away in 2017, since then they have just updated code at a bare minimum to conform with new R cran code change requirements.

Comment: I think in the future it may cease to operate altogether if new maintainers do not come forward, and unlike the fraudster who tried to appropriate fOptions code, lately , something so valuable and an incredible quantitative finance resource will be wasted.

Comment: It is open source.  You can _step_ forward and help, and some new maintainers have made new releases.  Maintenance takes effort just like rewriting or extending code.

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest version of fOptions package by entering the following in R:

```
install.packages("fOptions", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Answer (score 0):

fOptions is available on github for use, from what I have read someone tried to misappropriate the code for profit, or some devious use. Cran had to deprecate it from their servers, the GITHUB code runs fine I run it all the time. Archived code will most likely just refer you to Rmetrics github repository anyway. Most of the functional code itself the late Diethelm Wuertz took from the book complete book of Option pricing formulas by Espen Haug. Espen  gave his code in c++ and VBA. Diethelm converted most to R. However some of his original code like the hestonNandi model implementation are not that good over all. They need delicate calibration and many trials to be functionally usefull. But I am sure if Diethelm had lived it would have been different. As a general rule there is only bare maintenance of all Rmetrics libraries since the project inspiration passed away, that is Diethelm Wuertz in 2017 in a car crash.

Comment: "It's complicated."  CRAN is an extremely well and carefully curated repostiory currently hosting nearly 20k package.  So over its history likely in excess of 22k packages have been submitted, and nearly all are still availble directly, or in the archive. Only seven had to be withdrawn for "issues" related to IP, authorship. copyright.  I know nothing about the _specifics_ for this package, but I do know it is part of the small group of seven.  So if you or other need options functionality, maybe time to write a new package?

Comment: I have thought about maintaining and developing the code but at 63 I am not probably the best candidate as my years of good contribution are variable upon continuing health. And I am unsure if have the R language skills to so, not being a highly accomplished R programmer.